# Ruby : how to prevent modification of an array instance variable through an attribute reader

Tags: ruby, arrays, encapsulation, instance-variables, getter

sorry for this noob question... let's say we have :

```
class TestMe
 attr_reader :array

 def initialize
   @array = (1..10).to_a
 end
```

end

it is then possible to do :

```
>> a = TestMe.new
=> #<TestMe:0x00000005567228 @x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]>
>> a.array.map! &:to_s
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
>> a.array
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```

- this clearly goes against encapsulation, doesn'it ?
- is there any way to quickly protect the array variable from being changed ?
- ... or do i need to implement a deep-copy reader every time my instance variable has "destructive" methods ?

**EDIT** i read somewhere it is "bad OO" to expose an array instance variable. If it's true, why ?

Comment: I think your original question answers your seconds question about why exposing array instance variable is not that good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot do much with `attr_reader`, because `attr_reader :array` generates the following code:

```
def array; @array; end
```

If you don't want to expose array instance, you can return *Enumerator* of this array (external iterator). [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html) is a good iterator abstraction and does not allow you to modify original array.

```
def array; @array.to_enum; end
```

What good for encapsulation and what not depends on the abstraction your class presents. Generally this is not good for encapsulation to expose internal state of an object, including internal array. You may want to expose some methods that operate on the `@array` instead of exposing `@array` (or even its iterator) itself. Sometimes this is fine to expose array - always look at the abstraction your class presents.

Comment: many valid answers, but i chose yours because of your explanation on OO. "internal state of an object" made it clear to me... i'm self-taught so i still have a hard time wrapping my head around these concepts. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

How about returning a copy of the original array from getter:

```
class TestMe

  attr_writer :array

  def initialize
    @array = (1..10).to_a
  end

  def array
    @array.dup
  end

end
```

In that case you can't directly modify original array but with attribute writer you can replace it with the new one (if you need).

Answer (score 2):

Any instance can become immutable by calling freeze on it:

```
class TestMe
 attr_reader :array

 def initialize
   @array = (1..10).to_a
   @array.freeze
 end
end

a = TestMe.new
a.array << 11
# Error: can't modify frozen array
```

Comment: mmm... perhaps i have not been clear enough. What if i want my array to still be mutable, but only through a writer and not through the reader ?

Comment: @m_x Then don't use `attr_reader` and define custom getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the array to remain mutable, but not when returned through the reader, then don't return the array, but just a wrapper which exposes "safe" methods.

```
require 'forwardable'
class SafeArray
  extend Forwardable
  def initialize(array); @array = array; end
  # add the other methods you want to expose to the following line
  def_delegators :@array, :size, :each, :[], :map
end

class TestMe
  def initialize
    @array = (1..10).to_a
  end
  def array
    @wrapper ||= SafeArray.new(@array)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a specific attribute reader method that copies the original attribute works well, but keep in mind that **neither** `@array.dup` **nor** `Array.new(@array)` will perform a **deep copy**. Which means that if you have an array of arrays (like [[1, 2], [3, 4]]), none of the array's values will be protected against changes. To perform a deepcopy in ruby, the easiest way I found was this :

```
return Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(@array) )
```

Marshall.dump transforms any object into a string that can later be decoded to yield the object back (the process is called serializing).
This way, you get a deepcopy of the given object.
Easy but a bit dirty I have to admit.

Answer (score 0):

This is against encapsulation, but we can solve the problem by properly tuning the `getter method` of that attribute.

```
class TestMe

 def initialize
   @array = (1..10).to_a
 end

 def array
   Array.new(@array)
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You encapsulate by creating a method with the same name as your instance variable but make it end with equals sign. In your example that would be:

```
def array=
..
end
```

In that method you do whatever it is that you want to do before assigning new values to the array